# How to move a file while making the original one a symlink to the new location?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Suppose I have a file and a folder in my working directory:

```
>> tree
.
├── my-file
└── my-folder
```

To move `my-file` to `my-folder` and preserve a `my-file` in the original location with a symlink to the new location I have to do it in a few steps:

Move:

```
>> mv my-file my-folder
>> tree
.
└── my-folder
    └── my-file
```

Create symbolic link in the original location:

```
>> ln -s my-folder/my-file
>> tree
.
├── my-file -> my-folder/my-file
└── my-folder
    └── my-file
```

Is there a way to do it in one step? (and for multiple files?)

Something like the following:

```
>> tree
.
├── my-file
└── my-folder

>> move-and-create-symlink-command-??
>> tree
.
├── my-file -> my-folder/my-file
└── my-folder
    └── my-file
```

Comment: What is "one step" for you? If you want it to be one command, wrap both into a function. If you want the linking to only execute if the moving succeeded, connect both using `&&`, …

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of being able to connect them as one command. But I was wondering if there is already such a think, because it seems reasonable to be. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way as mentioned in the *[comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598556/how-to-move-a-file-while-making-the-original-one-a-simblink-to-the-new-location#)* by *[pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf)*; if you want the linking to only execute if the moving succeeded, connect both using `&&`. Other way is you can always create your custom commands whenever you want. You can create a custom shell function to perform the move and symlink creation in one step. Add the following function to your shell configuration file (e.g., `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` generally for `MAC`):

```bash
move_and_symlink() {
  mv "$1" "$2"
  ln -s "${2%/}/$1" .
}
```

Then, source your shell configuration file to make the new function available:

```
source ~/.bashrc  # or source ~/.zshrc based on your requirement
```

Now, you can use the `move_and_symlink` command to move a file and create a symlink in one step:

```bash
tree
.
├── my-file
└── my-folder

move_and_symlink my-file my-folder
tree
.
├── my-file -> my-folder/my-file
└── my-folder
    └── my-file
```

The above custom function takes two arguments: *the source file and the destination directory*. It first moves the file to the destination directory using `mv` and then creates a `symlink` to the new location in the original location with `ln -s`.

##### EDIT(For operating on multiple files h/t *[tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)*):

The above function can be amended for handling multiple files:

```bash
move_and_symlink() {
  # Get the last argument as the destination directory
  dest_dir="${!#}"
  
  # Iterate through all arguments except the last one (the source files)
  for ((i=1; i<$#; i++)); do
    src_file="${!i}"
    mv "$src_file" "$dest_dir"
    ln -s "$dest_dir/$src_file" .
  done
}

# Usage: move_and_symlink file1 file2 file3 destination_folder
```

[**Reference**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need the `%` in function?

Comment: It's not hard to extend this to operate on multiple files. A slight complication is that getting the _last_ of a list of arguments is a bit messy in Bash.

Comment: The `${variable%suffix}` [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) is documented in the manual. It produces the value of `variable` with `suffix` removed, if found.

Comment: @YFl For example:
If `$2` is `my-folder`, then `${2%/}` will be my-folder.
If `$2` is `my-folder/`, then `${2%/}` will also be my-folder.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Super useful.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the parameter expansion resource. It was something new for me. Will read up on it:) Just as much as get from the doc, if say this is the command `move_and_symlink file1 file2 file3 destination_folder` and I want to get `destination_folder` directory, I can use something like: `dest_dir="${!#}"` ryt? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That's right, but then you need more complex code than `ln -s "$@" "$dest_dir"` to symlink the files. Probably use an array instead.

Comment: @tripleee the last argument is ```${!#}```